# How to plot data in pandas by date and perform grouping at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I often find myself wanting to plot data in one column by another, but find it hard to group/separate them by a 3th column.

Suppose I have a sheet like this

[image]

How would I create the same plot in pandas?

BTW: I like that the x-axis is linear and not just group of dates aligned next to each other since it gives and idea about how close the measurements are made to each other within a group - but would be nice to know how to do both in case the distance is too far.

## UPDATE

The answer from @Ffisegydd has been very useful. However I was a bit too fast accepting the answer - I discovered that when trying out the code on an actual excel sheet. The problem is entirely my fault since I didn't provide an Excel sheet. @Ffisegydd was so kind to manually create the dataframe from my question, but working with excel files is a bit different.

I do apoligize. Here is an Excel file: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3216968/Example.xlsx

This is how far I got (in IPython notebook)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

path2file = r"C:\Example.xlsx"
_xl = pd.ExcelFile(path2file)
df = pd.read_excel(path2file, _xl.sheet_names[0], header=0)
df
```

[image]

```
df.Date = df.Date.apply( lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y.%m.%d').date() )
df
```

[image]

Here is where things go wrong:

```
pd.DataFrame( data= [df.Data, df.Group], columns = ['Data', 'Group'], index=df.Date)
```

Giving this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-231baa928f67> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.DataFrame( data= [df.Data, df.Group], columns = ['Data', 'Group'], index=df.Date)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    245                         index = _default_index(len(data))
    246                     mgr = _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns,
--> 247                                          dtype=dtype)
    248                 else:
    249                     mgr = self._init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
   4471     axes = [_ensure_index(columns), _ensure_index(index)]
   4472 
-> 4473     return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
   4474 
   4475 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes)
   3757         return mgr
   3758     except (ValueError) as e:
-> 3759         construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   3760 
   3761 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   3729         raise e
   3730     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 3731         passed,implied))
   3732 
   3733 def create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes):

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2,), indices imply (2, 12)
```

or doing this

```
pd.DataFrame( {'data': df.Data, 'group': df.Group}, index=df.Date)
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited my answer :) there is a comment with more detail on the actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `groupby` object and then iterate over the groups and plot.

Below is some code which takes your data and plots the two "groups". There is some extra formatting to make the graph look good as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

path2file = r"Example.xlsx"
_xl = pd.ExcelFile(path2file)
df = pd.read_excel(path2file, _xl.sheet_names[0], header=0) 

df.Date = df.Date.apply( lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y.%m.%d').date())
df.index = df.Date # Set the Date column as your index
del df['Date'] # Remove the Date column from your data columns

grouped = df.groupby('Group') # groupby object

# Normally you would just iterate using "for k, g in grouped:" but the i
# is necessary for selecting a color.
colors = ['red', 'blue']
for i, (k, g) in enumerate(grouped):
    plt.plot_date(g['Data'].index, g['Data'], linestyle='None', marker='o', mfc=colors[i], label=k)

plt.legend()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() # Format the dates with a diagonal slant to make them fit.

# Pad the data out so all markers can be seen.
pad = dt.timedelta(days=7)
plt.xlim((min(df.index)-pad, max(df.index)+pad))
plt.ylim(0,6)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: thank you very much for this. I experience some issues when trying to make your answer work on real Excel files. Please see the updated part of my question

Comment: Thank you! What a nice way of doing it

Comment: Why do the labels (legends) have 2 dots?

Comment: I think that's just the way they are formatted, showing that each data set is a circular marker of red/blue.

Comment: It seems a bit weird.. But I really like your solution since I can do more grouping withing the loop :)

Comment: It's to do with how matplotlib works. You could probably change it but that is an entirely different beast/question :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51892/discussion-between-norfeldt-and-ffisegydd)

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
df.pivot_table(rows=['Date'], cols=['Group'], values=['Data']).plot()
```

But be aware that each data point will be a 'mean' of the data points in a particular group for a given day

Comment: @Ffisegydd i do like his suggestion though (since some people looking at this question might want such a solution), but your are correct that your answer answers my question.

Comment: @Ffisegydd I agree with your comment. However, it might still help people for whom 'all' points is no a requriement. Will remove answer if that does not turn out to be the case

Comment: @user1827356 what if you have more columns ? how would you select the data column?

Comment: @Norfeldt I've updated the answer. The previous version did not do what I expected, at least in 0.12.0

Comment: @user1827356 thank you for that. I up voted your answer, but it got a down vote so it's now just zero